# use something to do something (with)

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Surely it is not quite ethical but is it grammatical to say: "I am going to use this stick to hit you." vs "I am going to use this stick to hit you **with**." (excuse my ending the sentence with a preposition)?

Comment: it's okay to end a sentence with a preposition but not in the way you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to use this stick **to hit** you. In this context, the use of the to-infinitive describes the purpose of the stick, so you don't need *with*.

*I am going to use this stick to hit you with* should be rewritten as *I am going to hit you with this stick.*